# Create tables using joinColumns?

Tags: jpa, join

I am trying to build a few simple tables with JPA, but I have problem get them working. I have total 4 tables: *lookup*, *group*, *keyword* and *groupkw*.

The *lookup* table has an Id field. This *loookup.id* field is used as foreign key in other tables.

In table *group*, an *id* column joins the *lookupid* column as the primary key; and in *keyword* table, an *id* column joins the *lookupid* column as the primary key as well.

The last table is *groupkw* table, it has three columns: *kwid*, *groupid* and *lookupid*. The *kwid* and *lookupid* is mapped to columns  *id* and *lookupid* in table *Keyword*; the *groupid* and *lookupid* is mapped to columns "id" and "lookupid" in table *group*.

For *group* and *keyword*, I have written annotated java classes to represent them and according to the unit tests, they are working fine. But for table *groupkw*, I can not get the right annotation class.

I have written some code for table *groupkw*:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="kwid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
@JoinColumn(name="lookupid", referencedColumnName = "lookupid", nullable = false)
})
public Keyword getKeyword() {
  return keyword;
}

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="groupid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
@JoinColumn(name="lookupid", referencedColumnName = "lookupid",
nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
})
public Group getgroup() {
  return group;
}
```

But seems not working, the EntityManagerFactory can not create the *groupkw* table. 
Would you please let me know if this is the right way to implement this table or there is some other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a column mapped twice, which is the case with your `lookupid` column. You're making it harder than necessary.

If I understand correctly, you have the following associations:

- Lookup - OneToMany - Group
- Lookup - OneToMany - Keyword
- Group - ManyToMany - Keyword

If that's right, you don't need to map the groupkw table as an entity: it's a join table, and can be handled by JPA.

You just need :

- Lookup (id PK)
- Group (id PK, lookupId FK)
- Keyword (id PK, lookupId FK)
- GroupKeyWord (groupId FK, keywordId FK), the PK of this table being the tuple (groupId, keywordId).